# Use request and response in Multer

Tags: node.js, multer

I'd like to use `request` and `response` when a file is not uploaded... But it seems not working in the callback's function...

My code :

```
app.use(multer({
  dest: './public/uploads/',
  limits: {
    fileSize: 819200
  },
  onFileSizeLimit: function (file, request, response) {
    fs.unlink('./'+file.path, function() {
      response.redirect('/soumettre-activite');
    });
  }
}));
```

Error message : `response.redirect is not defined`

Comment: Your error message says `request.redirect` but your code says `response.redirect`. Which is it?

Answer (score 2):

Multer is a middleware function so you can do something like this:

```
app.use('/my/route/upload/here', function(req, res, next) {
    var hd = multer({
        onFileSizeLimit: function (file) {
            fs.unlink('./'+file.path, function() {
              return res.redirect('/soumettre-activite');
            });
        }
    });
    hd(req, res, next);
});
```

**Update**

According to the issue [72](https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues/72) the `onFileSizeLimit` callback was removed, so now you need to use [the standard express way](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html) to show an error page, more details [here](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#error-handling).

Comment: I may be doing it wrong, but when I try to use standard express handling, LIMIT_FILE_SIZE errors don't get triggered until *after* the client has completely uploaded the file. Didn't the old onFileSizeLimit handler trigger *immediately* when an error was encountered thereby avoiding wasted upload time for files that would eventually be discarded anyway?